# Is there way I can do a "for loop" in Kusto query?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

**Context**: I'm trying to compute Daily Active Users/Monthly Active users(last 30days). For eg: if my Daily active users on 1st May 2022 is 1200, and Monthly active users for last days is 1600 (i.e. Last 30 days = 1st April 2022 to 1st May 2022). And I want this data rolling for up to 30 days in the past. More explanation below.

**Current query**: I'm able to get Daily active users and Monthly active users(last 30 days) for today's date(*using now()*) from below query.

```
Events
| AccountId == 'xyz'
| where timestamp between ((now()-31d)..(now()-1d))
| summarize MonthyDCount = dcount(userId) by AccountId, To = To=format_datetime((now()-1d),"dd-MM-yyyy"),From=format_datetime((now()-31d),"dd-MM-yyyy")
| join (Events
         | AccountId = 'xyz'
         | timestamp > ago(3d)
         | summarize dailyDcount = dcount(userId) by AccountId, DAUDate=format_datetime(timestamp,"dd-MM-yyyy"))
on ($left.AccountId == $right.AccountId) and ($left.To == $right.DAUDate)
| project AccountId, To, From, DAUDate, MonthlyDcount, dailyDcount
```

**Current Result:**

| AccountID | To | From | DAUDate | MonthlyDCount | dailyDCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 01-05-2022 | 01-04-2022 | 01-05-2022 | 1600 | 1200 |

**Expected Results:**

| AccountID | To | From | DAUDate | MonthlyDCount | dailyDCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 01-05-2022 | 01-04-2022 | 01-05-2022 | 1600 | 1200 |
| xyz | 30-04-2022 | 31-03-2022 | 30-04-2022 | 1580 | 1250 |
| xyz | 29-04-2022 | 30-03-2022 | 29-03-2022 | 1676 | 1499 |
| xyz | 28-04-2022 | 29-03-2022 | 28-04-2022 | 1560 | 1295 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |

Is it possible to achieve this in Kusto??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm trying to compute Daily Active Users/Monthly Active users(last 30days).*

You can consider using the built-in [User analytics plugins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/useranalytics).

> *Is there way I can do a "for loop" in Kusto query?*

It's not directly related to the content of your questions, but as this is the title of your question then i'll answer - you can achieve that using the [`partition` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/partitionoperator).